# Modify all textboxes position in notes page (powerpoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm learning to create small macros for powerpoint.

I would like to change the position of the slides within the notes page.
I created this small macro:

```
Sub Macro_resize ()
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 450
    .Width = 510
    .Left = 30
    .Top = 290
  End With
End Sub
```

I would like to apply it to all the slides, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to not work with `Select.` function.  You'd better `Dim` your range (all slides) and refer to that range.

```
Sub macro_resize()
Dim sld As Object
Dim shp As Object

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        With shp.Range
            .Height = 450
            .Width = 510
            .Left = 30
            .Top = 290
        End With
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work. 
I have this error "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"

Comment: It's the same. I have an error with this line:   
"Dim myrange As Range"

Comment: ok, seems that you cannot Dim a range, give it a last try with the new code.

Comment: Now the problem is with "With shp.Range". I don't know how to resolve. Now i need to start my little macro for each slide, and with 300 slides it can be a problem! :(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I normaly work with excel vba. Hope you can solve the problem.

Comment: Change shp.Range to just shp